# If $\text{supp} \hat f\subset B(R,0)$, then $\|\partial_\alpha f\|_{L^\infty}\leq C_{\alpha,n}R^{|\alpha|}\|f\|_{L^\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $f$ be a bounded function on $\mathbb R^n$,and the Fourier transform of $f$ is supported in the ball $B(R,0)$. Prove that there exists
$C_{\alpha,n}$ such that
$\|\partial_\alpha f\|_{L^\infty}\leq C_{\alpha,n}R^{|\alpha|}\|f\|_{L^\infty}$

Hint: consider $f * \phi $, where $\phi$ is a Schwartz function whose Fourier function equals $1$ in $B(R,0)$ and
vanishes out of $B(2R,0)$.

But I don’t know how to amplify left hand side at all. Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varphi\in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb R^n)$ be a fixed function such that $\hat\varphi=1$ on $B(1, 0)$ and $\operatorname{supp}\hat\varphi\subset B(2, 0)$. For each $R>0$, let
$$\phi_R(x)=R^n\varphi(Rx), \qquad x\in\mathbb R^n,\tag{$*$}$$
then $\hat\phi_R(\xi)=\hat\varphi(\xi/R)$, hence $\hat\phi_R=1$ on $B(R, 0)$ and $\operatorname{supp}\hat\phi\subset B(2R, 0)$. Note that $$\widehat{f*\phi_R}=\hat f\hat \phi_R=\hat f,$$
since $\hat\phi_R(\xi)=1$ if $\hat f(\xi)\neq0$. Therefore we have $f=f*\phi_R$, and thus $\partial_\alpha f=f*\partial_\alpha\phi_R$, so
$$\|\partial_\alpha f\|_{L^\infty}\leq \|f\|_{L^\infty}\|\partial_\alpha\phi_R\|_{L^1}.$$

It follows from $(*)$ that $\partial_\alpha \phi_R(x)=R^{|\alpha|+n}(\partial_\alpha\varphi)(Rx)$, hence
$$\|\partial_\alpha\phi_R\|_{L^1}=R^{|\alpha|}\|\partial_\alpha\varphi\|_{L^1}=C_{\alpha, n}R^{|\alpha|},$$
and this gives the desired inequality.

Comment: I know it!So I have to find a function g such that f = f * g.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Zero_Yang  Welcome to MSE! I'm very glad to be helpful. You should learn some latex really. If this answer helps you, you may consider to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it : )